# How to prioritize tests in scala?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am using scalatest's `FunSuite` to run my tests. I want to define 2 separate test classes that have a few tests in common, so I created a `BaseTest` class which I extended in `MainTest1` and `MainTest2`, in which I define additional specific tests (see code snippets below). I want the tests in `MainTest1` and `MainTest2` to execute in a specific order, *e.g.* test 4, 2, 1 and then 3. How do I achieve this?

```
class BaseTest extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfter{

    test("Check Content of file){

    //code to check content of a file
    }

    test("File is not empty"){

    //code to check file is not empty
    }

    test("Check a particular word in file"){

    //code to check particular word in file
    }

    }
```

---

```
class MainTest1 extends BaseTest{

        test("Check create file"){

        //code to check file creation
        }
    }
```

---

```
class MainTest2 extends BaseTest{

    test("Check download file"){

    //code to check file downloaded properly
    }
}
```

Comment: write a test method and enclose `test4, test2, test1, test3` in it.

Comment: then if test4 fails, test2, test3.. will not execute

Comment: Why do you need your tests to execute in a particular order? This seems like an anti-pattern. Also, please provide a minimal code example to make sure we understand your problem.

Comment: i have added code snippet, please check

Comment: You could define `test1()`, `test2()` *etc* methods in `BaseTest`, with `test("blah") { ... }` as their bodies. You could then call these methods in order from `MainTest1` and `MainTest2`. I will provide a full code sample once the question is not on hold anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your tests as methods and call them in the order you see fit from the children classes.

```
trait BaseTest extends FunSuite {

    protected def test1(): Unit = test("This is test 1") { ... }

    protected def test2(): Unit = test("This is test 1") { ... }

}

class MainTest1 extends BaseTest {

    // Arrange these is any order you see fit
    test3()
    test2()
    test1()

    protected def test3(): Unit = test("This is a test specific to MainTest1") { ... }

}

class MainTest2 extends BaseTest {

    // Arrange these is any order you see fit
    test2()
    test3()
    test1()

    protected def test3(): Unit = test("This is a test specific to MainTest2") { ... }

}
```

Comment: here, the problem is if test3() fails, test2() & test1() will not execute, how to overcome this?